# ValueError: attempt to get argmin of an empty sequence but the matrix is not empty

Tags: python, numpy

I'm two days trying to solve this issue without any improvement.
I have this code bellow:

```
if qtd > qtd_individuos:
          distancia_mutidao = crowding_distance(fitness)
          print("Distância de mutidão: \n{} População: \n{} Fitness: \n{}".format(distancia_mutidao, pop, fitness))

          while (len(pop) > qtd_individuos):
              menor_ = distancia_mutidao.argmin()
              pop = np.delete(pop, menor_)
              fitness = np.delete(fitness, menor_)
              distancia_mutidao = np.delete(distancia_mutidao, menor_)
```

Where distancia_mutidao, pop, and fitness are NumPy arrays. And I'm trying to remove the correspondent lower value from the matrixes distancia_multidao, pop, and fitness.
I'm plotting these values, and I got this:

```
Distância de mutidão: 
[1.         0.15555981 0.11988209 0.09177397 1.         0.14718105
 0.08688929 0.14825755 0.01990456 0.11109479 0.02420551 0.22930752
 0.16252269 0.29968407 0.03971115] População: 
[[1 3 1 3 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1 1 2]
 [3 3 3 3 1 1 3 1 3 2 1 3 2 3 2]
 [2 3 3 2 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 1 3 1 1]
 [1 3 2 1 2 1 1 3 3 2 3 1 3 2 1]
 [3 3 2 3 2 3 1 2 1 2 2 3 3 3 2]
 [3 1 1 1 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 1 2 1 3]
 [1 3 2 1 2 1 1 3 3 2 3 1 3 1 3]
 [3 1 1 1 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 2 2 2 3]
 [2 3 3 2 1 2 1 1 2 3 1 1 3 1 1]
 [3 1 1 1 3 3 2 3 2 2 3 1 2 2 1]
 [2 1 2 3 3 2 3 3 2 1 3 1 2 1 3]
 [3 1 1 1 3 3 2 2 2 3 2 3 3 3 3]
 [2 1 1 1 1 2 3 2 2 1 3 3 2 2 3]
 [2 1 3 1 1 2 3 3 2 1 3 1 2 2 1]
 [1 3 2 3 2 1 1 3 3 2 3 1 3 2 1]] Fitness: 
[[ 8.         58.73167024]
 [19.         49.34529535]
 [12.         55.08177469]
 [14.         53.10238747]
 [20.         46.55252601]
 [16.         51.15094548]
 [15.         51.74934794]
 [18.         49.47316082]
 [12.         55.08177469]
 [15.         52.503985  ]
 [17.         51.2657001 ]
 [20.         47.5785755 ]
 [14.         53.62171346]
 [13.         55.32419517]
 [16.         51.44574786]]
```

So, the matrix distancia_mutidao is not empty...  Why am I getting this error "ValueError: attempt to get argmin of an empty sequence"?

Comment: I guess your `distancia_mutidao` is not really a `numpy.matrix` or `numpy.array`, but something else. Print `type(distancia_mutidao)` to find out what it is.

Comment: Actually, I got it resolved right now... The problem was with my delete function.  The correct is: `pop = np.delete(pop, menor_,axis = 0)`
              `fitness = np.delete(fitness, menor_, axis = 0)`, but I was not using the "axis".  Because of that, how `len(pop)` was my stopping condition, the size of distance_multidao decreased, but that of pop did not.